# How to replace a rendered plot with its own plot_click info in R Shiny?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, shiny

My app is supposed to load certain data as input file (in this post i will give a part of it written in form of data frame so you can use to run my example). and then plot three plots . i want that when the user click oh the plot at the top of page , a first  new plot will be displayed based on the click info and when the new plot will be displayed then i want to plot a second new plot based on the click info of the first new plot.

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(scales)
library(grid)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(officer)
library(svglite)
library(rvg)
library(readxl)
library(tools)
library(rsvg)


body <- dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(
    tabBox(
      
      # The id lets us use input$tabset1 on the server to find the current tab
      id = "tabset1",height = 750,width=20,
      tabPanel("Summary",dataTableOutput(outputId = "table")),
      tabPanel("Visualization",sliderInput("scalegvt","Scale  Data by:",  min = 0, max = 100, value = c(70,100)),plotOutput("p1", height = 1000,click = "plot_click")
      )
    )
  )
)
  side<- dashboardSidebar(  
    width = 290,
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Summary",tabName = "Summary") ,  
      uiOutput('choose_Da'),
      
      selectizeGroupUI(
        id = "m",
        inline = FALSE,
        params = list(
       Lot = list(inputId = "Lot", title = "Lot"),
          wafer = list(inputId = "wafer", title = "wafer"),
         M_datum = list(inputId = "M_Datum", title = "M_Datum"),
          Yield = list(inputId = "Yield", title = "Yield")
          
          
        )
      ),inline=FALSE,
      menuItem("Visualization",tabName = "Visualization")
      
    ))
  ui <- function(request) {
    
    dashboardPage(
      
      dashboardHeader(title = "Yield Report",titleWidth = 290),
      side,
      body
      
    )
  }
  
  server = function(input, output,session) { 
    
    
    
    newscale <- reactive({
      req(input$scalegvt)
    })
    
    mydt<-data.frame(Lot=c(rep("A",4),rep("b",5),rep("n",3),rep("x",2)),M_Datum=as.Date(c("2012-06-05","2012-06-15","2012-06-10","2014-11-17","2014-03-18","2014-06-15","2014-06-10","2014-06-17","2015-11-27","2016-08-15","2016-09-10","2016-10-27","2017-09-10","2017-10-12")),wafer=(c(rep(5,14)+1:14)),Yield=c(rep(10,14)+57))
  
  
dz<-reactive({
 req(res_mod())
  dat<-res_mod() 
  dt<-dat[dat$M_Datum >=input$dateRange[1] & dat$M_Datum <= input$dateRange[2],]
  
  
  dt[,2]<-as.Date(format(as.Date(dt[,2]), "%Y-%m-01"))
  
  req(dt$M_Datum,dt$Yield)
  dr<-data.frame("M_Datum"=dt$M_Datum,"Yield"=dt$Yield)
  
  req(dr$M_Datum,dr$Yield)
  dx<-aggregate(Yield~M_Datum,dr,mean)
  req(dx$M_Datum,dx$Yield)
  dx$M_Datum<-format(dx$M_Datum, "%b %Y")
  
  return(data.frame("M_Datum"=dx$M_Datum,"Yield"=dx$Yield))
  })


#observeEvent(input$plot_click,

#{ a<- reactive(nearPoints(dz(),  input$plot_click, threshold = 10, maxpoints = 1,
            # addDist = F))
# b<-reactive(match(substr(a()$M_Datum,1,3),month.abb))


# req(res_mod())
 #dat<-res_mod() 
 #dt<-dat[dat$M_Datum >=input$dateRange[1] & dat$M_Datum <= input$dateRange[2],]
 #dt<-dt[substr(dt$M_Datum,6,7)==as.character(b()),]
 
 
 
 
 #req(dt$Lot,dt$Yield)
 #dr<-data.frame("Lot"=dt$Lot,"Yield"=dt$Yield)
 
# req(dr$Lot,dr$Yield)
# dx<-aggregate(Yield~Lot,dr,mean)
# req(dx$Lot,dx$Yield)
 
# dza<-data.frame("Lot"=dx$Lot,"Yield"=dx$Yield)
# output$p2 <- renderPlot({  ggplot(dza, aes(x = Lot,y = Yield,group = 1)) +
 #  geom_point()})

 
#})
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  

    

  
  
  
  
  output$choose_Da <- renderUI({
    dateRangeInput('dateRange',
                   label = 'Filter  by date',
                   start = min(mydt$M_Datum) , end = max(mydt$M_Datum),min=min(mydt$M_Datum),max=max(mydt$M_Datum)
    )
  })
  

 res_mod <- callModule(
    module = selectizeGroupServer,
    id = "m",
   data =  mydt,
    vars = c("Lot","M_Datum","Yield","wafer"),
   inline=FALSE
    
  )
  
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    
    
   dato<-res_mod() 
    
    return(dato[dato$M_Datum >= input$dateRange[1] & dato$M_Datum <=  input$dateRange[2],]) },
    options = list(scrollX = TRUE))
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  filtredplot<-reactive({
    
    req(res_mod())
    dat<-res_mod() 
    dt<-dat[dat$M_Datum >=input$dateRange[1] & dat$M_Datum <= input$dateRange[2],]
    
    
    dt[,2]<-as.Date(format(as.Date(dt[,2]), "%Y-%m-01"))
    
    req(dt$M_Datum,dt$Yield)
    dr<-data.frame("M_Datum"=dt$M_Datum,"Yield"=dt$Yield)
    
    req(dr$M_Datum,dr$Yield)
    dx<-aggregate(Yield~M_Datum,dr,mean)
    req(dx$M_Datum,dx$Yield)
    
    dz<-data.frame("M_Datum"=dx$M_Datum,"Yield"=dx$Yield)
    dz$M_Datum<-factor(format(dz$M_Datum, "%b %Y"), levels=format(sort(unique(dz$M_Datum)),"%b %Y"))
    hline_data <- data.frame(y = c(mean(dz$Yield)-sd(dz$Yield),mean(dz$Yield), mean(dz$Yield)+sd(dz$Yield)), type = factor(c(2, 1, 2)), 
                             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    ggplot(dz, aes(x=M_Datum, y=Yield,group = 1)) +
      geom_point(size=7,colour="#007A9D",shape=4) +
                                                                                     
                                                                                     
                                                                                     
                                                                                     
                                                                                     theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))+
                                                                                       
                                                                                       
                                                                                       
                                                                                       theme(legend.direction = "horizontal", legend.position = "top", legend.key = element_blank(), 
                                                                                             legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "white"),
                                                                                             
                                                                                             axis.text.y.left = element_text(color = "#007A9D"),
                                                                                             axis.title.y.left  = element_text(color = "#007A9D"),
                                                                                             plot.title = element_text(color="#007A9D")
                                                                                       )+
                                                                                       
                                                                                       ylab("Mean Yield")+
                                                                                       xlab("")+
                                                                                       ggtitle(paste0("FCM-Yield Trend :","  ",paste0(c(input[["m-Customer_Name"]],input[["m-Local_Process_Id"]],input[["m-Process_Family"]],input[["m-MEMS_flag"]],input[["m-Device"]]),collapse = ",")))+
                                                                                       ylim(newscale())+
                                                                                       
                                                                                       
                                                                                       geom_hline(data = hline_data, 
                                                                                                  aes(yintercept = y, linetype = type, colour = type)) +
                                                                                       scale_colour_manual(values = c("#007A9D", "#EF783D"), 
                                                                                                           labels = c("Mean", "Mean+-sd"),
                                                                                                           name = "Key:") +
                                                                                       scale_linetype_manual(values = 1:2, 
                                                                                                             labels = c("Mean", "Mean+-sd"),
                                                                                                             name = "Key:")
                                                                                     
                                                                                     
                                                                                     
                                                                                     
                                                                                     
                                                                                     
                                                                                     
                                                                                     
  })
  
  
  output$p1<-renderPlot({
    
    
    filtredplot()                })
  }
  shinyApp(ui,server)
```

in that part of code turned to comment i have tried using the clik info to transform that month name to number to use it in order to filter data that means i want to plot the lot (x axis ) vs Yield ( as y axis in form of mean(avarage) ) so i can get average of yield pro lot in that month and then when i click again i want to get a second plot  showing yield ( y axis not aggregated as mean this time)  vs wafer (x axis) and of course only for that lot chosen by clickíng the first new plot.

Comment: @r2evans do you have solution?

Comment: @r2evans my code work well without any error.Two new plots :the first new one is a result of clicking the existing plot.The second new one is a result of clicking on the first new one .It is clear and i do not think you have any  solution since you were the whole time about packages .You were just bothering me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code posted is not a **minimal** reproducible example [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  I did not go through it. But here is an MRE to achieve the task you have described: to output a second plot (p2) based on the `plot_click` of a first plot (p1) using `nearPoints()` shiny function.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

data <- mpg  

ui <- basicPage(
  plotOutput("p1", click = "plot_click"),
  plotOutput("p2")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$p1 <- renderPlot({    
    ggplot(data, aes(x = displ, y = cty)) + 
      geom_point()
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$plot_click,{ 
    a <- nearPoints(data,  
                    input$plot_click, 
                    threshold = 10, 
                    maxpoints = 1,
                    addDist = F)$model

    if (length(a) > 0) {
      df <- data[data$model == a, ]  
      output$p2 <- renderPlot({
        ggplot(df, aes(x = model, y = displ, group = 1)) +
          geom_point()
      })
    }
     
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**EDITED** here is the above solution using your code. A click on p1 outputs a second plot p2, and a click on p2 outputs a third plot p3. I made the plots smaller because I'm working on a laptop. Note that because your sample data is small, not all datapoints result in a valid click. But there are enough "good" points to test out the solution.

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(ggplot2)

body <- dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(
    tabBox(
      
      # The id lets us use input$tabset1 on the server to find the current tab
      id = "tabset1",height = 750,width=20,
      tabPanel("Summary",dataTableOutput(outputId = "table")),
      tabPanel("Visualization",
               sliderInput("scalegvt","Scale  Data by:",  min = 0, max = 100, value = c(70,100)),
               plotOutput("p1", height = 300, width = 300, click = "plot_click_p1"),
               plotOutput("p2", height = 300, width = 300, click = "plot_click_p2"),
               plotOutput("p3", height = 300, width = 300,)
      )
    )
  )
)
side <- dashboardSidebar(  
  width = 290,
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Summary",tabName = "Summary") ,  
    uiOutput('choose_Da'),
    
    selectizeGroupUI(
      id = "m",
      inline = FALSE,
      params = list(
        Lot = list(inputId = "Lot", title = "Lot"),
        wafer = list(inputId = "wafer", title = "wafer"),
        M_datum = list(inputId = "M_Datum", title = "M_Datum"),
        Yield = list(inputId = "Yield", title = "Yield")
        
        
      )
    ),inline=FALSE,
    menuItem("Visualization",tabName = "Visualization")
    
  ))
ui <- function(request) {
  
  dashboardPage(
    
    dashboardHeader(title = "Yield Report",titleWidth = 290),
    side,
    body
    
  )
}

server = function(input, output,session) { 
  
  
  
  newscale <- reactive({
    req(input$scalegvt)
  })
  
  mydt<-data.frame(Lot=c(rep("A",4),rep("b",5),rep("n",3),rep("x",2)),M_Datum=as.Date(c("2012-06-05","2012-06-15","2012-06-10","2014-11-17","2014-03-18","2014-06-15","2014-06-10","2014-06-17","2015-11-27","2016-08-15","2016-09-10","2016-10-27","2017-09-10","2017-10-12")),wafer=(c(rep(5,14)+1:14)),Yield=c(rep(10,14)+57))
  
  
  dz<-reactive({
    req(res_mod())
    dat<-res_mod() 
    dt<-dat[dat$M_Datum >=input$dateRange[1] & dat$M_Datum <= input$dateRange[2],]
    
    
    dt[,2]<-as.Date(format(as.Date(dt[,2]), "%Y-%m-01"))
    
    req(dt$M_Datum,dt$Yield)
    dr<-data.frame("M_Datum"=dt$M_Datum,"Yield"=dt$Yield)
    
    req(dr$M_Datum,dr$Yield)
    dx<-aggregate(Yield~M_Datum,dr,mean)
    req(dx$M_Datum,dx$Yield)
    dx$M_Datum<-format(dx$M_Datum, "%b %Y")
    
    return(data.frame("M_Datum"=dx$M_Datum,"Yield"=dx$Yield))
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(input$plot_click_p1, { 
    a <- nearPoints(dz(),  
                    input$plot_click_p1, 
                    threshold = 10, 
                    maxpoints = 1,
                    addDist = F)
    
    b <- match(substr(a$M_Datum,1,3),month.abb)
    
    req(res_mod())
    dat <- res_mod() 
    dt  <- dat[dat$M_Datum >=input$dateRange[1] & dat$M_Datum <= input$dateRange[2],]
    dt  <- dt[substr(dt$M_Datum,6,7)==as.character(b),]
    
    req(dt$Lot, dt$Yield)
    dr <- data.frame("Lot"=dt$Lot,"Yield"=dt$Yield)
  
    req(dr$Lot, dr$Yield)
    dx <- aggregate(Yield~Lot,dr,mean)
    
    req(dx$Lot,dx$Yield)
    dza <- data.frame("Lot"=dx$Lot,"Yield"=dx$Yield)
    
    output$p2 <- renderPlot({  
      ggplot(dza, aes(x = Lot,y = Yield,group = 1)) +
      geom_point()
    })
  
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$plot_click_p2, {
    output$p3 <- renderPlot({
      
      
      test <- nearPoints(mydt,  
                 input$plot_click_p2, 
                 threshold = 10, 
                 maxpoints = 1,
                 addDist = F)
      
      str(test)
      ggplot(test, aes(x = Lot, y = Yield)) +
        geom_point()
    })
  })

  output$choose_Da <- renderUI({
    dateRangeInput('dateRange',
                   label = 'Filter  by date',
                   start = min(mydt$M_Datum) , end = max(mydt$M_Datum),min=min(mydt$M_Datum),max=max(mydt$M_Datum)
    )
  })
  
  
  res_mod <- callModule(
    module = selectizeGroupServer,
    id = "m",
    data =  mydt,
    vars = c("Lot","M_Datum","Yield","wafer"),
    inline=FALSE
    
  )
  
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    
    dato <- res_mod() 
    return(dato[dato$M_Datum >= input$dateRange[1] & dato$M_Datum <=  input$dateRange[2],]) 
    
  },options = list(scrollX = TRUE))

  filtredplot <- reactive({
    
    req(res_mod())
    dat <- res_mod() 
    dt <- dat[dat$M_Datum >=input$dateRange[1] & dat$M_Datum <= input$dateRange[2],]
    
    
    dt[,2] <- as.Date(format(as.Date(dt[,2]), "%Y-%m-01"))
    
    req(dt$M_Datum,dt$Yield)
    dr<-data.frame("M_Datum"=dt$M_Datum,"Yield"=dt$Yield)
    
    req(dr$M_Datum,dr$Yield)
    dx<-aggregate(Yield~M_Datum,dr,mean)
    req(dx$M_Datum,dx$Yield)
    
    dz<-data.frame("M_Datum"=dx$M_Datum,"Yield"=dx$Yield)
    dz$M_Datum<-factor(format(dz$M_Datum, "%b %Y"), levels=format(sort(unique(dz$M_Datum)),"%b %Y"))
    hline_data <- data.frame(y = c(mean(dz$Yield)-sd(dz$Yield),mean(dz$Yield), mean(dz$Yield)+sd(dz$Yield)), type = factor(c(2, 1, 2)), 
                             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    ggplot(dz, aes(x=M_Datum, y=Yield,group = 1)) +
      geom_point(size=7,colour="#007A9D",shape=4) +
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))+
      theme(legend.direction = "horizontal", legend.position = "top", legend.key = element_blank(), 
            legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "white"),
            axis.text.y.left = element_text(color = "#007A9D"),
            axis.title.y.left  = element_text(color = "#007A9D"),
            plot.title = element_text(color="#007A9D")
      ) +
      ylab("Mean Yield")+
      xlab("")+
      ggtitle(paste0("FCM-Yield Trend :","  ",paste0(c(input[["m-Customer_Name"]],input[["m-Local_Process_Id"]],input[["m-Process_Family"]],input[["m-MEMS_flag"]],input[["m-Device"]]),collapse = ",")))+
      ylim(newscale())+
      geom_hline(data = hline_data, 
                 aes(yintercept = y, linetype = type, colour = type)) +
      scale_colour_manual(values = c("#007A9D", "#EF783D"), 
                          labels = c("Mean", "Mean+-sd"),
                          name = "Key:") +
      scale_linetype_manual(values = 1:2, 
                            labels = c("Mean", "Mean+-sd"),
                            name = "Key:")
  })
  
  output$p1 <- renderPlot({
    filtredplot()                
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution! But is it possible to get another plot based on the click info from the new plot also .i tried it it works but the third plot just shows up after clicking the first plot and waiting untill clicking the first new plot rather it shows up directly with it.

Comment: it seems the solution does not work for reactive data and reactive plots like in my  post .could you try your approach using the code i posted .

Comment: Yes, you can get a third plot (p3) based on a click on the second plot (p2). Make sure they have different click ids, `plotOutput("p1", click = "plot_click")`, then `plotOutput("p2", click = "plot_click_p2")`. Add `observeEvent(input$plot_click_p2, {})` and in it `output$p3` to `plotOutput("p3")`. Regarding reactivity: the clicks are already reactive, so I don't think there's a need to make "a" and "b" reactive. I removed the reactive() function on "a" and "b" and I was able to output p2 and p3 using your code.

Comment: i am really grateful .The problem is that i tried again without reactive but it doesent function .Are you sure you managed to run my code? can you please edit your solution using my code because i really need a solution snce my chef is waiting for that . i do not know how you manged to flter that data based on b? and then  plot the desired plot . am stuced there since two weeks

Comment: I've updated the solution using your code. Take a look.

Comment: App does not work always and it works for some points and some others not.

Comment: That has to do with the way you're filtering the data before you pass it to ggplot. If you print the data you're passing to ggplot, you'll see that you're passing empty data sometimes. To debug, print the data when you click, then print the filtered data you pass to ggplot.

Comment: That is true ! i remarked that alone but i did not understand the debugging solution you suggest.

Comment: One way to quickly debug is to introduce `print(dza)` or `str(dza)` for example at specific points in the code to check the values of those objects. You can see I left an `str(test)` in the code as I was checking it. This will output to the console. A more effective way is to use `browser()`. The app will stop at that point and you'll see the state of different variables in the environment.

Comment: i can not undertasnd how printing that or this data will help in displaying the plot??!!

Comment: You're right, it wont. I was just suggesting it as a strategy to debug your code and figure how you're ending up with empty data, see if you need to adjust your filter, or display a message to the user "no data for this point" or however you want to handle empty data.

Comment: in fact on my real app which 320 MG it is always showing nothing means not working and for the example in my post it is just working for only one points and not always hhh.